# PyInstaller Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file ot directory: 'myKivyfile.kv'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, kivy-language

So I have tried to get my python / kivy project into a standalone "exe". I succeeded in making it "onedir" but after it compiled (with no errors) into a single exe, it doesn't work. The app window just flashes and closes. Command I put in to compile: `pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=download.ico --debug=all --add-data filefinder.kv;. filefinder.py`. I added the debug flag to figure out what's causing it to crash and got the following window errors:

```
Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap

Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Traceback: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', ' File 
"Pyinstaller\\loader\\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 20, in <module>\n', ' File]
```

The full 3rd error

[image: full]

For troubleshooting purposes I also compiled it in a windowless mode to get the command prompt output and hopefully shed some light and this issue and in one line I found this gem:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file ot directory: 'filefinder.kv'`

So it has something to do with my ".kv" file. The problem is, I don't know what! I have read the [docs on what to do when things go wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) but it didn't help me. So I am asking for your help. I am happy to provide any information you may need.

Additional info:
Python: 3.9.1
System: Windows 10 Pro
Kivy: 2.0.0
Pyinstaller: Latest 5.0 (experimental) I have tried the stable version but got the same results

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself! (8 months ago). All right, I know this answer is really late, but in case that someone stumbles upon this issue, I want them to know the solution.

**The issue is caused by the lack of kivy libraries which you need to copy to the folder in which your .exe file is.**

**You can download these libraries from my github here:** https://github.com/6outtaTen/kivy_libs

Also if you want to see me explain this topic and issue in depth, you can watch my video on YouTube:

[How to make a standalone exe file from your kivy project! 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Hx0q5Sopg)